# How to fix "Non exhaustive 'when' statements on sealed class/interface" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sealed-class, kotlin-when, kotlin-sealed

Non exhaustive `when` statements on sealed class/interface will be prohibited in **Kotlin 1.7**.

I have a `sealed class State` and it's children:

```
sealed class State {
    object Initializing : State()
    object Connecting : State()
    object Disconnecting : State()
    object FailedToConnect : State()
    object Disconnected : State()
    object Ready : State()
}
```

In some cases I want to handle only particular items, not all, for example:

```
val state: State = ... // initialize
when (state) {
    State.Ready -> { ... }
    State.Disconnected -> { ... }
}
```

But I get a warning (in **Kotlin 1.7** I guess it will be an error), saying:

> Non exhaustive 'when' statements on sealed class/interface will be prohibited in 1.7, add 'Connecting', 'Disconnecting', 'FailedToConnect', 'Initializing' branches or 'else' branch instead

Is it a good practice to use empty `else -> {}` branch here like in the next code?

```
when (state) {
    State.Ready -> { ... }
    State.Disconnected -> { ... }
    else -> {}
}
```

Or need to add every item with an empty brackets like in the following code?

```
when (state) {
    State.Ready -> { ... }
    State.Disconnected -> { ... }
    State.Connecting,
    State.Disconnecting,
    State.FailedToConnect,
    State.Initializing -> {}
}
```

Comment: Using _else_ as in your first example is fine. What you also can do is to use _if (state == State.Ready) { ... } else if (state == State.Disconnected) { ... }_ with no else clause.

Comment: That's really a personal/team preference thing IMHO. I would lean towards the latter approach, just as a reminder of what cases you are ignoring.

Answer (score 2):

In `when` statements, the `else` branch is mandatory in the following conditions:

- `when` has a subject of a `Boolean`, `enum`, or `sealed` type, or their nullable counterparts.
- branches of `when` don't cover all possible cases for this subject.

Source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it is not a good practice to add `else` in `when` clauses when it's being used to compare subclasses of a sealed class.

When there is a breaking change due to addition of a new subclass you would want the compiler to highlight all the `when` comparisons so that you can go in and place appropriate logic or maybe do nothing at all use sites; either way it will be an informed decision. Instead, if we had just added `else` then  the new subclass will get handled by it which might not what we want at all the use sites.